# Can TOR Browser hide my online activity at work? Or only from the ISP?

Tags: browser, tor, network-traffic

I am not sure how TOR browser works, and wanted to know if I get it at work - will the IT guys be able to see what I am surfing? What kinda of info can they see anyhow?

Comment: At work, your IT guys _are_ your ISP.  They can (at least) see the amount of bandwidth you are using, and can see you are using and encrypted tunnel. Many enterprise UTM firewalls can detect and stop this kind of traffic, as well as email the admin with who's doing it.  Be aware, it may be grounds for dismissal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes but ...

IT Guy will see that you are using TOR, however he will not see which site you are surfing to.

As mentioned, try to check before that this is allowed. After all your boss is paying all firewall, ISP cost and all, he may whish to ensure your using it for his own business.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot assume that your activity will be hidden from your IT department. While TOR should prevent them from sniffing your traffic as it goes over the network, that isn't all you have to worry about.

1. Even if they can't see where you are browsing to, your IT department can definitely see that you *are* using TOR. This may make them rather suspicious.
2. Presumably your IT department has Administrator rights on the computer you are using. If they wanted to find out what you are doing, they could install monitoring software that could log all your keystrokes, and even take screenshots of everything you are doing.

Comment: I like this answer best because of the further detail provided. Thank's @Izam